# How to get R.attr.colorPrimary in pre lvl 21 devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I know that you should be able to get the primary color of current theme by calling

```
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
int color = typedValue.data;
```

However, even with AppCompat v7:21 this doesn't seem to work in pre 21 devices ("No such static field" at runtime). However if I try to declare such an attribute somewhere it says that it is already defined while compiling (the file it says to contain a definition doesn't contain such). So how on earth does on get access to themes color values from code (not in the layout files)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was just being plain stupid. In order to use `R.attr.colorPrimary` in pre 21.

> You cannot use android.R but rather the resources of your application.